# Scipy sparse matrix from list of list with integers

Tags: python, scipy, sparse-matrix

How to make a scipy sparse matrix from a list of lists with integers (or strings)?

```
[[1,2,3],
 [1],
 [1,4,5]]
```

Should become:

```
[[1, 1, 1, 0, 0],
 [1, 0, 0, 0, 0],
 [1, 0, 0, 1, 1]]
```

But then in scipy's compressed sparse format?

Comment: python has zero based indexing. do you really have it like this or you can start from 0 ?

Comment: In reality I have words/sentences, which I figured I can turn into integers if that would help. That method would start with zeroes.

Comment: so you also know the shape of matrix in advance?

Comment: Yea, I do actually! The input is not square, but the output would be `n` by `n`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume you want to have a 5 by 5 matrix at the end. also indices start from 0.

```
In [18]:import scipy.sparse as sp


In [20]: a = [[0,1,2],[0],[0,3,4]]
In [31]: m = sp.lil_matrix((5,5), dtype=int)

In [32]: for row_index, col_indices in enumerate(a):
    m[row_index, col_indices] = 1
   ....:     

In [33]: m.toarray()
Out[33]: 
array([[1, 1, 1, 0, 0],
       [1, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [1, 0, 0, 1, 1],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0]])
```